# Excel VBA runtime error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel VBA and am attempting to write code that will take the input of two NBA teams (a home and away team), test to make sure the name of the teams exist in my table, and output the names of the entered teams if they are found. Below is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim homeTeam As Variant
Dim awayTeam As Variant
Dim h As Variant
Dim a As Variant

'declare variables

homeTeam = InputBox("Enter the Home team", "Home Team")
awayTeam = InputBox("Enter the Away team", "Away Team")

'Use input boxes to obtain both the home and away teams

Set h = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(homeTeam)
Set a = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(awayTeam)

With h.Range("A2:A31")
    h = .Find(homeTeam)
    If h Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Error: Home Team not found. Please Enter again")
    End If
End With

Range("I1").Value = h
Range("J1").Value = h

End Sub
```

I am encountering runtime error 91 with this code, which I tried to remedy by setting values for h and a. 
As mentioned previously, I am brand new to this programming, so any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: [Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506(v=vs.60).aspx) is thrown if "You attempted to use an object variable that isn't yet referencing a valid object. ". And the debugger should have shonw you the code line in which the error occurs. I suspect `If h Is Nothing Then` because there `h` is not an `Object` since it was not set via `Set` before. But your whole program logic is not clear to me. So without knowing the structure of the `ActiveSheet` used more help will not be possible.

Comment: @AxelRichter In the code I'm seeing `h` is "set" (as is `a`) to the result of a Find. But then the Find is being repeated, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Isn't it way easier to use `application.worksheetfunction.countif` to find out if the team exists? `If Application.worksheetfunction.countif(Activesheet.Range("A2:A31"),homeTeam) = 0 then Msgbox ("Error")` etc..

Comment: @Cindy Meister: Yes at first `h` is set via `Set` but then in `h = .Find(homeTeam)` the `Set` is not used. So either the error comes in `With h.Range("A2:A31")` because `h` is an `Object` but `Nothing` after the first `Find` because of the `homeTeam` was not found or the error comes in `h = .Find(homeTeam)` because of `h` **was** an `Object` in start of `With` but now tries be set without `Set`. There was my first suspicion wrong. But, as said already, the debugger should have told that and, as you said too, the whole program logic is not clear.

Comment: @AxelRichter You're right - my bad. Chalk it up to tiredness!